# How can I make window.showmodaldialog work in chrome 37?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser

We have a huge web application where we use `window.showmodaldialog` for alerts, confirmations and popups. Since Chrome version 37 this call has been disabled.

Is there any quick workaround to make `window.showmodaldialog` work in the latest version of Chrome?

***I am adding here a workaround for window.showmodaldialog, although this is not a perfect workaround because this will not break the code execution as showmodaldialog was doing,  instead this will open the popups.***

```
window.showModalDialog = function (url, arg, feature) {
        var opFeature = feature.split(";");
       var featuresArray = new Array()
        if (document.all) {
           for (var i = 0; i < opFeature.length - 1; i++) {
                var f = opFeature[i].split("=");
               featuresArray[f[0]] = f[1];
            }
       }
        else {

            for (var i = 0; i < opFeature.length - 1; i++) {
                var f = opFeature[i].split(":");
               featuresArray[f[0].toString().trim().toLowerCase()] = f[1].toString().trim();
            }
       }



       var h = "200px", w = "400px", l = "100px", t = "100px", r = "yes", c = "yes", s = "no";
       if (featuresArray["dialogheight"]) h = featuresArray["dialogheight"];
        if (featuresArray["dialogwidth"]) w = featuresArray["dialogwidth"];
       if (featuresArray["dialogleft"]) l = featuresArray["dialogleft"];
        if (featuresArray["dialogtop"]) t = featuresArray["dialogtop"];
        if (featuresArray["resizable"]) r = featuresArray["resizable"];
       if (featuresArray["center"]) c = featuresArray["center"];
      if (featuresArray["status"]) s = featuresArray["status"];
        var modelFeature = "height = " + h + ",width = " + w + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ",model=yes,alwaysRaised=yes" + ",resizable= " + r + ",celter=" + c + ",status=" + s;

        var model = window.open(url, "", modelFeature, null);

       model.dialogArguments = arg;

    }
```

***Just put this code in the head section of page.***

Comment: Yes, showmodaldialog is no longer working in the latest chrome. http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html

Comment: This is what Google suggested you should do https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Answer (score 40):

I put the following javascript in the page header and it seems to work. It detects when the browser does not support showModalDialog and attaches a custom method that uses window.open, parses the dialog specs (height, width, scroll, etc.), centers on opener and sets focus back to the window (if focus is lost). Also, it uses the URL as the window name so that a new window is not opened each time. If you are passing window args to the modal you will need to write some additional code to fix that. The popup is not modal but at least you don't have to change a lot of code. Might need some work for your circumstances.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // fix for deprecated method in Chrome 37
  if (!window.showModalDialog) {
     window.showModalDialog = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

        var w;
        var h;
        var resizable = "no";
        var scroll = "no";
        var status = "no";

        // get the modal specs
        var mdattrs = arg3.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < mdattrs.length; i++) {
           var mdattr = mdattrs[i].split(":");

           var n = mdattr[0];
           var v = mdattr[1];
           if (n) { n = n.trim().toLowerCase(); }
           if (v) { v = v.trim().toLowerCase(); }

           if (n == "dialogheight") {
              h = v.replace("px", "");
           } else if (n == "dialogwidth") {
              w = v.replace("px", "");
           } else if (n == "resizable") {
              resizable = v;
           } else if (n == "scroll") {
              scroll = v;
           } else if (n == "status") {
              status = v;
           }
        }

        var left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight / 2) - (h / 2);
        var targetWin = window.open(arg1, arg1, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=' + status + ', menubar=no, scrollbars=' + scroll + ', resizable=' + resizable + ', copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        targetWin.focus();
     };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It seems IE has same problems too. If we override the function by removing the first `if`, it works in all 3 major browsers.

Comment: Any sample in ***jsfiddle*** ? http://jsfiddle.net/grj4x5k9/ sample using _HTML5 dialog_ (with this problems)

Comment: Best answer if you are looking for a quick workaround!

Answer (score 15):

From http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/09/02/reenable-showmodaldialog-in-chrome/

It's deprecated by design. You can re-enable showModalDialog support, but only temporarily – until May of 2015. Use this time to create alternative solutions.

Here’s how to do it in Chrome for Windows. Open Registry Editor (regedit) and create following key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures`

Under the `EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures` key create a string value with name `1` and value of `ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil20150430`. To verify that the policy is enabled, visit chrome://policy URL.

---

***UPDATE:*** If the above didn’t work for you here’s another method to try.

1. Download Chrome ADM templates from http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates
2. Extract and import policy relevant to your locale (e.g. windows\adm\en-US\chrome.adm. You can import either via `gpedit.msc`or using these utilities on Home editions of windows: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2008/05/07/lgpo-utilities.aspx)
3. Under “Adminstrative Templates” locate Google Chrome template and enable “Enable Deprecated Web Platform Feautes”.
4. Open the feature and add “ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil20150430″ key.

Comment: do you know how to do fix this in Mac?

Comment: @sanjeev40084 I haven't tried it myself, but according to http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures under Preference Name `EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures` you set the value `<array><string>ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil20150430</string></array>`

Comment: I believe you should name string value ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil20150430 instead of ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil201504301.

Comment: Gotta love downvotes on 2-year old answer with no explanation. But if you are still trying to use `showModalDialog` and vent your frustration via downvotes - I feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 6):

A very good, and working, javascript solution is provided here :
https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog

I personnally used it, works like before for other browser and it creates a new dialog for chrome browser.

Here is an example on how to use it :

```
function handleReturnValue(returnValue) {
    if (returnValue !== undefined) {
        // do what you want
    }
}

var myCallback = function (returnValue) { // callback for chrome usage
    handleReturnValue(returnValue);
};

var returnValue = window.showModalDialog('someUrl', 'someDialogTitle', 'someDialogParams', myCallback); 
handleReturnValue(returnValue); // for other browsers except Chrome
```

Comment: Interesting how 3 answers copied my mention of the polyfill by niutech.

Answer (score 5):

This article ([Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)) seems to suggest that showModalDialog has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to temporarily enable a deprecated feature. According to the MDN documentation for [showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog), there's already a polyfill [available on Github](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog).

I just used that to add `windows.showModalDialog` to a legacy enterprise application as a userscript, but you can obviously also add it in the head of the HTML if you have access to the source.

Answer (score 2):

The window.returnValue property does not work directly when you are opening a window using window.open() while it does work when you are using window.showModalDialog()

So in your case you have two options to achieve what you are trying to do.

**Option 1 - Using window.showModalDialog()**

In your parent page

```
var answer = window.showModalDialog(<your page and other arguments>)
if (answer == 1)
 { do some thing with answer }
```

and inside your child page you can make use of the window.returnValue directly like

```
window.returnValue = 'value that you want to return';
```

**showModalDialog** halts the executions of the JavaScript until the dialog box is closed and can get a return value from the opened dialog box when its closing.But the problem with showModalDialog is that it is **not supported on many modern browsers**. In contrast window.open just opens a window asynchronously (User can access both the parent window and the opened window). And the JavaScript execution will continue immediately. Which bring us to Option 2

**Option 2 - Using window.open()**
In your parent page write a function that deals with opening of your dialog.

```
function openDialog(url, width, height, callback){
if(window.showModalDialog){
    options = 'dialogHeight: '+ height + '; dialogWidth: '+ width + '; scroll=no'
    var returnValue = window.showModalDialog(url,this,options);
    callback(returnValue)
}
else {
    options ='toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height; 
        var childWindow = window.open(url,"",options);
        $(childWindow).on('unload',function(){
            if (childWindow.isOpened == null) {
                childWindow.isOpened = 1;
            }
            else {
                if(callback){
                    callback(childWindow.returnValue);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

}

And whenever you want to use open a dialog. Write a callback that deals with the return value and pass it as a parameter to openDialog function

```
function callback(returnValue){
if(returnValue){
    do something nice with the returnValue
}}
```

And when calling the function

```
openDialog(<your page>, 'width px', 'height px', callbak);
```

Check out an article on how to [replace window.showModalDialog with window.open](http://dilanwijenayake.blogspot.com/2012/12/replace-windowshowmodaldialog-with.html)

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.

Answer (score 1):

I use a polyfill that seem to do a good job.

https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog

http://niutech.github.io/showModalDialog/demo.html

Comment: Thanks this worked for me... and i voted your answer

Comment: Interesting how 3 answers copied my mention of the polyfill by niutech.

Answer (score 1):

## Create a cross browser ModalDialog

```
function _showModalDialog(url, width, height, closeCallback) {
    var modalDiv,
        dialogPrefix = window.showModalDialog ? 'dialog' : '',
        unit = 'px',
        maximized = width === true || height === true,
        w = width || 600,
        h = height || 500,
        border = 5,
        taskbar = 40, // windows taskbar
        header = 20,
        x,
        y;

    if (maximized) {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        w = screen.width;
        h = screen.height;
    } else {
        x = window.screenX + (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2) - (border * 2);
        y = window.screenY + (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2) - taskbar - border;
    }

    var features = [
            'toolbar=no',
            'location=no',
            'directories=no',
            'status=no',
            'menubar=no',
            'scrollbars=no',
            'resizable=no',
            'copyhistory=no',
            'center=yes',
            dialogPrefix + 'width=' + w + unit,
            dialogPrefix + 'height=' + h + unit,
            dialogPrefix + 'top=' + y + unit,
            dialogPrefix + 'left=' + x + unit
        ],
        showModal = function (context) {
            if (context) {
                modalDiv = context.document.createElement('div');
                modalDiv.style.cssText = 'top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;position:absolute;z-index:50000;';
                modalDiv.onclick = function () {
                    if (context.focus) {
                        context.focus();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                window.top.document.body.appendChild(modalDiv);
            }
        },
        removeModal = function () {
            if (modalDiv) {
                modalDiv.onclick = null;
                modalDiv.parentNode.removeChild(modalDiv);
                modalDiv = null;
            }
        };

    // IE
    if (window.showModalDialog) {
        window.showModalDialog(url, null, features.join(';') + ';');

        if (closeCallback) {
            closeCallback();
        }
    // Other browsers
    } else {
        var win = window.open(url, '', features.join(','));
        if (maximized) {
            win.moveTo(0, 0);
        }

        // When charging the window.
        var onLoadFn = function () {
                showModal(this);
            },
            // When you close the window.
            unLoadFn = function () {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                if (closeCallback) {
                    closeCallback();
                }
                removeModal();
            },
            // When you refresh the context that caught the window.
            beforeUnloadAndCloseFn = function () {
                try {
                    unLoadFn();
                }
                finally {
                    win.close();
                }
            };

        if (win) {
            // Create a task to check if the window was closed.
            var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                try {
                    if (win == null || win.closed) {
                        unLoadFn();
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }, 500);

            if (win.addEventListener) {
                win.addEventListener('load', onLoadFn, false);
            } else {
                win.attachEvent('load', onLoadFn);
            }

            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadAndCloseFn, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should make clear that the IE path (`window.showModalDialog()`) _blocks_ until dialog closes, while the "Other browsers" path returns immediately.  If you need blocking behaviour, this is not going to work.

Comment: Suggestion: _sample usage_? Any sample in ***jsfiddle***?

Answer (score 1):

```
    (function() {
        window.spawn = window.spawn || function(gen) {
            function continuer(verb, arg) {
                var result;
                try {
                    result = generator[verb](arg);
                } catch (err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                }
                if (result.done) {
                    return result.value;
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
                }
            }
            var generator = gen();
            var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, 'next');
            var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, 'throw');
            return onFulfilled();
        };
        window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function(url, arg, opt) {
            url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
            arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
            opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
            var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();
            var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
            dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
            dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 4px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
            document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
            document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                dialog.close();
            });
            dialog.showModal();
            //if using yield
            if(caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
                        var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                        document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                        resolve(returnValue);
                    });
                });
            }
            //if using eval
            var isNext = false;
            var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function(stmt) {
                if(isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                    return isNext = true;
                return false;
            });
            dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
                var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
                eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
            });
            throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
        };
    })()

;

**Explanation:
------------**
The best way to deal with showModalDialog for older application conversions is use to `https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog` inorder to work with show modal dialogs  and if modal dailog has ajax calls you need to create object and set the parameters of function to object and pass below...before that check for browser and set the useragent...example: agentStr = navigator.userAgent; and then check for chrome

var objAcceptReject={}; // create empty object and set the parameters to object and send to the other functions as dialog when opened in chrome breaks the functionality
    function rejectClick(index, transferId) {
        objAcceptReject.index=index;
        objAcceptReject.transferId=transferId;

     agentStr = navigator.userAgent;

                var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

                if (msie > 0) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
                {
                    var ret = window.showModalDialog("/abc.jsp?accept=false",window,"dialogHeight:175px;dialogWidth:475px;scroll:no;status:no;help:no");   

                    if (ret=="true") {
                        doSomeClick(index);
                    }

                } else if ((agentStr.indexOf("Chrome")) >- 1){
                spawn(function() {

                    var ret = window.showModalDialog("/abcd.jsp?accept=false",window,"dialogHeight:175px;dialogWidth:475px;scroll:no;status:no;help:no");   

                    if (ret=="true") {// create an object and store values in objects and send as parameters
                        doSomeClick(objAcceptReject.index);
                    }

                });

                }
                else {
                    var ret = window.showModalDialog("/xtz.jsp?accept=false",window,"dialogHeight:175px;dialogWidth:475px;scroll:no;status:no;help:no");   

                    if (ret=="true") {
                        doSomeClick(index);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Interesting how 3 answers copied my mention of the polyfill by niutech.

Answer (score 0):

> The window.showModalDialog is deprecated (Intent to Remove:
>   window.showModalDialog(), Removing showModalDialog from the Web
>   platform). [...]The latest plan is to land the showModalDialog removal
>   in Chromium 37. This means the feature will be gone in Opera 24 and
>   Chrome 37, both of which should be released in September.[...]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's deprecated. Spent yesterday rewriting code to use Window.open and PostMessage instead.