# modal popup is not working on chrome 37 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popupwindow

I have an issue with modal popup on chrome 37 and above. The popup is working on lower version without any issue.

I am using with

```
var win = window.showdialog();
```

Please help

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/window-showmodaldialog-is-not-working-in-chrome-37