# use window.open in case of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

since `window.showModalDialog` doesn't work on chrome, I'm using it in case of `firefox` and in `chrome` I'm using window.open but my problem is that the return value of window.open is undefined maybe because the javascript continue before i close the child window so I tried to put the code in this condition `if (returnValue.closed)` .. but the problem is that the child window is loading all the time and i can't choose my value from it.

This is my code:

```
if (window.showModalDialog) {
   var retVal = window.showModalDialog(...)

if (!window.showModalDialog) {
 var retVal = window.open(...);
            while (a == 0) {
                if (retVal.onload()) {
                    if (retVal.closed) {
                        if (retVal != null) {...
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Whoah, dude. Your question is not clear here. Please break your code out into code blocks and maybe add some punctuation to your question if you can. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make window.showmodaldialog work in chrome 37?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showModalDialog is a deprecated feature. You can see http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html for more details.

I recommend you to use another option (from many available out there) of a javascript "popup" that will also "freeze" the rest of the page like:

- https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog - dialog-polyfill
- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals - Bootstrap modal
- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation - JQueryUI modal
- etc...

And you will need to find another way to pass the return value back to your page, depending on the option you choose to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm using the first option https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog but the problem is that arguments of the function are lost after using the open.showModal Dialog. I mean if i want to set the return value in textbox by document.getElementById(one_of_the_function_arguments) it's not working because this argument is lost in google chrome only!!! Do you have any idea why?? Thanks again