# Button Not Working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button that call's a javascript function with a fancybox. 
This is working fine in all browsers except google chrome.

Here is the javascript function :

```
            function batch_popup(list) 
            { 

                if(window.showModalDialog)
                {

                    var start_date      = $('#begin_datum').val();
                    var end_date        = $('#eind_datum').val() ;

                    if(end_date != '')
                    {
                        end_date = end_date + " 23:59";
                    }

                    var batch_bedrag    = $('#batch_bedrag').val();//zoeken.batch_bedrag.value;
                    var klant           = $('#klant').val();//zoeken.klant.value;
                    var locatie         = $('#locatie').val();//zoeken.locatie.value;
                    var ordernr         = $('#ordernr').val();//zoeken.product.value;
                    var betaalwijze     = $('#betaalwijze').val(); //zoeken.betaalwijze.value;


                    self.parent.$.fancybox({
                        href:  self.parent.$('base:first').attr('href')+ '/batchgenereren/?#TB_iframe&modal=true',
                        type: 'iframe',
                        modal: true                         
                    });
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $('[name=checkbox_selectie]').attr('action', self.parent.$('base:first').attr('href')+ '/batchgenereren/?begin_datum='+start_date+'&eind_datum='+end_date+'&batch_bedrag='+batch_bedrag+'&klant='+klant+'&locatie='+locatie+'&ordernr='+ordernr+'&betaalwijze='+betaalwijze+'')

                    $('[name^=fancybox-frame]', self.parent.document).each(function(){
                        $('[name=checkbox_selectie]').attr('target', $(this).attr('name'));
                    })

                    $('[name=checkbox_selectie]').submit();
                    }, 300);

                }
                else
                {
                    melding('004-1','Uw browser wordt niet ondersteund door ProTruckWash','Neem voor meer informatie contact op met Promo Systems\nTel: 0184-602300, E-mail: support@protruckwash.nl');
                }
            }
```

This is my button what is calling my js function :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ico-button" onclick="batch_popup(xajax.getFormValues('checkbox_selectie'));">
```

I really have no idea why it's not working in Google Chrome...

Comment: `window.showModalDialog === undefined` in chrome

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the best way to replace this code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37

Answer (score 0):

Replaced window.showModalDialog with window.open and it works now ! Thanks