# chromium CEF showModalDialog issue

Tags: javascript, delphi, delphi-7, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am using chromium CEF3 with Delphi latest code.Where i am using showModalDialog. Its working quit fine but one issue.Below is code

```
 var ret = showModalDialog(url, dlgArgs, options);
```

It does allow click parent that i don't want. what i want it should freeze the parent window like IE does.I also tried with window.open but it also did not work.

Comment: [How can I make window.showmodaldialog work in chrome 37?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37) and [Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Chromium version CEF is based. Since version 37, Chrome doesn't support modal dialogs