# Is there any alternate for Model dialog box in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I need to do same functionality in chrome browser like window.showModalDialog property in IE browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make window.showmodaldialog work in chrome 37?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a Javscript framework) like in [this](http://extremedev.blogspot.de/2011/03/windowshowmodaldialog-cross-browser-new.html) article.