# window.openDialog does not work

Tags: javascript

The app I am working on used windows.showModalDialog which depreciated, so I replaced it with window,.open which workd fine but with one issue - it is not modal. I have found that one can use window.open Dialog instead but replacing window.open with window.openDialog broke my links.

I had

```
ret = window.open(target, "", "scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=300");
```

which worked, so I tried:

```
ret = window.openDialog(target, "", "scrollbars=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=300");
```

which did not. Can someone help me fix it so it works?

Comment: `window.openDialog` was never standardized, and isn't supported anywhere

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935216/window-showmodaldialog-replacement

Comment: @adeneo, do I have any other options?

Comment: @Niki9696, one of the questions in the link was never answered, and pollifil seems like an overkill.

Comment: Sure there are options, `openDialog` only lets you pass data to the new window, but that can be done easily with any window, so you don't need it.

Comment: Sure you have alternative: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, does this dialog allows interaction with the parent page?

Comment: @ElenaDBA not fully like the actual .showModalDialog but this should be good enough, see example [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

Comment: Shandow Wizard, I've decided to go with your suggestion. Could you post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the parameter in the Window.openDialog, the extra parameter should come after WindowFeatures parameter like 
Window.openDialog("any url", "name", "", "feature", arg1,arg2);

Comment: yes, I got that from reading the documentation. Those parameters are optional and I am not passing any