# Window.showModalDialog is not working in chrome. Is there any work around?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

We are using extjs 3.4 version.  We are also using normal html, not html5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make window.showmodaldialog work in chrome 37?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37)

Comment: The linked question above will give you an explanation, but there is no answer other than create your own.

Comment: We have to fix this using only javascript, above explanation is not working. I want a modal window. but showmodaldialog is not working in chrome.

Comment: It's been deprecated.  You need to create your own dialog or use an existing framework that includes one, like bootstrap or jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

Its a known issue in chrome browser

you can use `window.open();`

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=200, left=500, width=800, height=600");
```