# ShowModalDialog not supported in Chrome

Tags: javascript

```
Window.open()
```

Is not returning the value

Like

```
Var retVal = Window.showModalDialog();
```

How to get it for the Chrome browser?

Comment: I remember `showModalDialog` is deprecated and you should avoid using it, most browsers removed it's functionality

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog):  "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How can I make `showModalDialog` work in Chrome 37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663053/how-can-i-make-window-showmodaldialog-work-in-chrome-37)

Comment: If i use window.open() it will not return value from chield window to parent.

Comment: @SagarThakarePatil That is correct.  And?

Comment: I have to use that return value for my fields is there any alternative. Any suggestions.

Comment: `is there any alternative` I suppose you could take a look at the two links I found for you.

Comment: When i used <dialog></dialog> Error: xhtml 1.0 transitional : Element Dialog is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Of course, `Window.showModalDialog` is a JavaScript method unique to Internet Explorer, and no other browser supports this specific method.

If you don't consider the incompatibility of the method, you can use `Window.open` to override `Window.showModalDialog` instead.

Or refer to the link below, which mentions a compatible alternative.

https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog